# Is there a difference between a choke, a reactor, and an inductor?

Tags: inductor, terminology, choke

I've seen all three of these terms used interchangeably. But once when I did so, I was told I was using one of the terms incorrectly. Are these terms, in fact, equivalent? Or are there differences between them?

Comment: Fundamentally they're all the same, but their characteristics are optimized towards different applications.

Comment: They all mean the same thing just like capacitor and condenser mean the same thing.

Comment: I had the same question, and found this helpful document
:
White Paper: What's in a name? Inductors, Chokes, Reactors, Filters... - Bel Fuse https://www.belfuse.com/resources/whitepaper/signaltransformer/wp-ST-Inductors-Chokes-Reactors-Filter.pdf

Answer (score 3):

While all 3 refer to the same type of component, an inductor, their usage is application specific.

reactor An electromagnetic device, the primary purpose of which is to introduce 
inductive reactance into a circuit.

inductor A device consisting of one or more associated windings, with or without a magnetic core, for introducing inductance into an electric circuit.

choke coil An inductor used in a special application to impede the current in a circuit over a specified frequency range while allowing relatively free passage of the current at lower frequencies.

Comment: "Introducing inductive reactance" is exactly the same as "introducing inductance" and, in my mind, so is the idea behind a choke. Is there some internet definition you can link to?

Answer (score 1):

My take is that they essentially refer to the same elementary component (the inductor), but in a different configuration or called differently in different applications (meaning they can be optimised differently). I can't tell for reactor VS inductor as I rarely saw the former but I suspect they are exactly the same thing as they should both bring a certain amount of [reactance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance) to the signals proportional to said signals frequencies (the imaginary term of impedance, resistance being the real term). As for the [chokes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_%28electronics%29), they usually are two inductors packaged together in a 4 terminal component (wound in opposite directions on the same core) that you can use directly on your lines to block high frequency and common mode AC.

[image]

The picture illustrates inductors (2 terminals) and chokes (4 terminals)

Note: I'm not a fan of the term reactor, as a reactor could also be a capacitor. It can bring the same amounts of reactance as an inductor, but at different frequencies.